# Kafka connect FileStreamSink not exactly once

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I was thinking of using FileStreamSink Kafka Connect connector for some storage job, but from what I understand, it's not possible to have exactly once semantics when using this file connector ( I can write a record to the file and then crash before committing to Kafka).
Before going to another kind of solution ( s3 sink connector offer EOS for instance) , I just want to make sure I'm right and FileStreamSink does not offer EOS.

Someone can confirm?

Comment: You could use Minio for a "local S3". I've gotten the S3 connector working with it (assuming you wanted local FS anyway)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct, it does not. The FileStream connectors are really only for demo/PoC use, they're not designed to be 'production-grade' with the functionality that one might expect of such a thing (such as EOS).

As you say, the [S3 sink does support EOS](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-to-amazon-s3-exactly-once).